# Validate Fields (Mandatory and Optional) in Repeating Record of XML message

Tags: xml, schema, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have to validate an incoming XML message (sample below) into BizTalk before processing further.
The 'Details' (repeating) records can come in any order in the XML message.

```
<Document>
    <Details>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <Name>DEF</Name>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <Name>GHI</Name>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <Name>JKL</Name>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <Name>MNO</Name>
    </Details>
</Document>
```

I am extracting all the 'Name' field values in a loop in Orchestration, but am unable to validate it.

The XML should be Valid if it meets below 2 criteria:

1. The 'Document' Record MUST have 3 (Mandatory) 'Details' records with 'Name' element matching 'ABC', 'DEF' & 'GHI'
2. The 'Document' Record COULD have up-to 2 (Optional) 'Details' records. If it does, the 'Name' element MUST match 'JKL' or 'MNO'

Comment: So are ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, & MNO the only valid values?  If so you could have the schema validation to part of it by only allowing those values, as well as setting the Min Occurrence to 3 and the Max Occurrence to 5.   In the Orchestration you could execute some XPaths to check that  'ABC', 'DEF' & 'GHI' exists, for which you don't even need to loop.

Comment: Thanks @Dijkgraaf. Schema is such that it could have other valid values as well depending on few other fields. Post checking those other field values in incoming message in Orchestration, I'm now validating this part. So can't set Min/Max Occurs on schema.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments, you will want to execute a XPath in a Expression shape e.g.

```
nNumberItemsABC = System.Convert.ToInt32(xpath(MsgName,"count(/*[local-name()='Document' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Details' and namespace-uri()=''][Name='ABC']/*[local-name()='Name' and namespace-uri()=''])"));
nNumberItemsDEF = System.Convert.ToInt32(xpath(MsgName,"count(/*[local-name()='Document' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Details' and namespace-uri()=''][Name='DEF']/*[local-name()='Name' and namespace-uri()=''])"));
nNumberItemsGHI = System.Convert.ToInt32(xpath(MsgName,"count(/*[local-name()='Document' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='Details' and namespace-uri()=''][Name='GHI']/*[local-name()='Name' and namespace-uri()=''])"));
```

And then have a Decide shape that checks to see if the mandatory ones exist (equal to 1)